# Mi programa contador en tkinter solo aumenta 1 y nada mas en python con tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa contador en el que cada vez que toque el boton "+" tiene que aumentar el numero que se muestra luego de la etiqueta "contador:",pero solo puedo hacer que aumente de 0 a 1 y no aumenta nada mas. Soy nueva en esto de interfaces graficas.

Mi codigo:

```
def sumar():
    resultado.set(numero+1)

root=Tk()
root.title("Contador")

numero=0
resultado=IntVar()

Label(root,text="Contador:").grid(row=0,column=0)
Entry(root,justify=CENTER,state="disable",textvariable=resultado).grid(row=0,column=1)
Button(root,text="+",command=sumar).grid(row=0,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: eso se debe a que haces `numero+1`, pero `numero` vale `0` toda la vida del programa, pues nunca lo cambias, y `0+1` es `1`.

Comment: Uh si,me habia dado cuenta de ese error hace unos cuantos minutos.